# Which data structure is best for swapping operations?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

Which data structure is most suitable to store elements that should be swapped quite frequently? Both linked lists and arrays were named as the favorites for this kind of operations, but I wonder about the reasoning...

Comment: I heard like Linked list only best for swapping. Because in array swapping we are using addition memory location. That's why i'm asking about you guys

Comment: Your question is badly formatted, supply more data, what language you are developing, what performance aspect you are most interested in??

Comment: Okay then You said how to format. I have doubt so only i posted if you  interest in update answer means please update otherwise please don't do like this and all. It's my request

Comment: Don't consider any language and all. Just consider time and space.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct answer is 'well, it depends, but usually an Array (Vector) is the way to go; if we talk about Linked List, it should be a Doubly Linked List at least'.

Let's assume we have some [Singly Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_lists):

```
...->$el1->$el2->$el3->$el4->$el5...
```

... and we have references to $el2 and $el4 elements (that should be swapped). Technically, what we need to do is...

```
1) assign the address of `$el4` (or `$el3->next`) to the `$el1->next` pointer
2) assign the address of `$el2` (or cached `$el1->next`) to the `$el3->next` pointer
3) assign the value of `$el4->next` to the `$el2->next` pointer
4) assign the value of `$el2->next` to the (previously cached) `$el4->next` pointer
```

... and that's it, essentially 0(1) efficiency. Easy, eh?

The catch here is that there's no easy way (=0(1)) to get the 'previous' elements (`$el1` and `$el3`) here. Both `$el4` and `$el2` store addresses of their `nexts` (`$el5` and `$el3` respectively) only.

You can, of course, use [Doubly Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) instead:

```
...$el1<->$el2<->$el3<->$el4<->$el5...
```

Referring the `prev` elements here will be as easy as the `next` ones, so we'll need to...

```
1-2) swap values of `$el2->prev->next` and `$el4->prev->next`,
3-4) swap values of `$el4->next`       and `$el2->next`
```

But wait, there's more! We have to update `prev` pointers now as well:

```
5-6) swap values of `$el4->prev`       and `$el2->prev`
```

As you probably already saw, it's 3 'value swap' operations here.

With vectors, it's a single swap:

```
[$el1][$el2][$el3][$el4][$el5]

1) assign data-value of $el2 to some temp variable;
2) assign data-value of $el4 to $el2;
3) assign data-value of this temp variable to $el4;
```

Of course, in theory this can be slower than in the previous approach (if this 'data-value' is so huge that copying it takes more time than copying a pointer to it thrice). But in practice it's pointers to such huge data that are stored in both arrays and linked-lists.